# RC Circuit Problem

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

[image]

I am confused with the above problem. It is an example problem from my workbook.

I doubt how can we write 1000/s as a voltage source ?

EDIT: I know that a dc voltage source can be written as V/s in laplace domain. I am confused with the modelling of capacitor in case of position2.
Please help me to understand this problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of \$s\$ in converting from equations based on the differential of time into the Laplace domain? The operator \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t}\$ on a variable of interest is replaced by \$s\$, \$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d} t^2}\$ on that same variable is replaced by \$s^2\$. In general, \$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d} t^n}\$ is replaced by \$s^n\$. The variable on interest itself, not as a differential of time, would be \$s^0=1\$ and a constant would be \$s^{-1}\$. Since the starting voltage is a constant, that's how to represent that constant, \$1000\cdot s^{-1}\$.

Comment: That's just how the Laplace domain works. You can prove it by applying the definition of the Laplace Transform.

Comment: Please help me with this problem https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359493/calculation-of-steady-state-power-limit

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that it is an "Ideal Voltage Source", the moment the switch is closed, the voltage at point 1 goes from 0 to 1000 V, this can be modelled by a unit step function of magnitude 1000. And the Laplace transform of that will be 1000/s.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at some [Laplace transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

From the table in the link it says that 1 in time domain translates to \$\frac{1}{s}\$ in Laplace domain.

---

Here's another way of thinking about it:

- 1 in Laplace domain is \$\delta(t)\$ in time domain
- \$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t)=1 \text{ and }\delta(t)=0\text{ when t $\not=$ 0}\$
- \$\frac{1}{s}\$ in Laplace domain is integration in time domain
- Multiplication in Laplace domain is convolution in time domain

So if we continuously make impulses, then we essentially have a constant value. So that's what \$1 × \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1}{s}\$ is actually doing, it's integrating all the impulses.

Comment: I am confused in case of position 2 and not position 1. But I got it now. Thanks

Comment: "*EDIT: I know that a dc voltage source can be written as V/s in laplace domain. I am confused with the modelling of capacitor in case of position2. Please help me to understand this problem.*", lol. Your question definitely didn't reflect that.

Comment: I just look at the Laplace domain as being a differential domain. Integrating moves the powers up by 1. So \$k\cdot s^{-1}\$ after solution becomes \$k\cdot x^0\$; \$k\cdot s^{0}\$ after solution becomes \$k\cdot x^1\$; etc. There is the wonderful aspect of eulers and group theory behind all this, too. \$s\$ represents the entire set of complex number addition (vertical and horizontal shifts) and multiplication (stretching and rotation) in a single concept at once and the power function preserves the underlying group structure of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

E = 1000 V is a constant voltage and the Laplace transform of a constant is : $$\text{constant/S}$$
You can see [this](https://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-LT1.pdf)

Comment: But it is showing constant voltage source when switch is at position 2

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not understand your question. What you really do not understand is the equivalent circuit in the Laplace domain of point (i)?